# Difference between Continuous and discrete setting in Finite Element Method

Tags: finite-element-method

I often hear the lecturer making comparisons between continuous and discrete setting in FEM (topics related to Poisson equation Mixed FEM). My vague understanding is that it is impossible to find a solution in the continuous setting, hence we introduce the discrete setting followed by interpolation and other stuff. My current idea about the whole thing is:

1. We develop a variational formulation (test function and trial functions are elements of $V$, an infinite dimensional space or an arbitrary space which we claim to have the solution)
2. Say that we will find a solution in $V_h ⊂ V$. ($V_h$ a finite dimensional subspace of $H_1$, $H(\mathrm{div})$, …)
3. Define/Find basis function to span the space(is it the interpolation space?)
4. Formulation of mass matrix and other processes to find the solution.

I couldn't see any references online to these specific keywords "discrete setting" and " continuous setting". If one cannot find a solution in the continuous setting, why studying it?

Can someone give me a clear understanding on these concepts?

Comment: We can find analytic solutions for the strong version of the equations for simples cases.

Comment: @nicoguaro can you tell me what exactly is  " continuous setting" and "discrete setting" ?

Comment: I can't, I haven't been in your classes with you. But I would say that the "continuous setting" refers to looking for solutions in the infinite dimensional space $V$ and the "discrete setting" refers to looking for "solutions" in the finite dimensional subspace $V_h \subset V$.

Comment: Thank you. That's all I wanted !

Comment: In that case, let me rewrite the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been in your classes with you, so I can't tell for sure what your lecturer means. Probably, the best option is to ask her directly.

That being said, I would say that the "continuous setting" refers to looking for solutions in the infinite dimensional space $V$ and the "discrete setting" refers to looking for "solutions" in the finite dimensional subspace $V_h \subset V$. In the Finite Element Method, the finite dimensional space is generated from the interpolation functions defined over your elements.